# What's the simplest way to define default groups and permissions?

Tags: python, django, permissions

### The goal

Being able to automatically create few groups with predefined permissions (including permissions created automatically by `django.contrib.auth.signals`).

### My Struggle

Apparently there are two ways to do this:

1. fixtures
2. signals

The problems with going with the first option are:

- You can't possibly know, before hand (except maybe by running the script once and noting the IDs on paper), what are the IDs of the predefined permissions (`add_`, `delete_`, `change_`). -
- If you decide to create your own permissions you also don't know how to populate the `"pk"` field in the fixture, giving that some permissions have already been created.

The problem with going with the second option is:

- Apparently your signals are run before any other signals, including `django.contrib.auth.signals`, therefore you are not able to call its predefined permissions and add them to your groups.

Not only that, but with a simple:

```
def create_initial_groups(**kwargs):
    staff_group     = Group(name = 'Staff')
    clients_group   = Group(name = 'Clients')

    staff_group.save()
    clients_group.save()
```

and:

```
signals.post_syncdb.connect(
    create_initial_groups,
    dispatch_uid = 'unique_app_identifier.listeners.create_initial_groups'
)
```

I get an:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "auth_group_name_key" DETAIL:  Key (name)=(Staff) already
>   exists.

Even with a clean database (running `drop schema public cascade; create schema public;` on `psql` before `python manage.py syncdb`).

### Question

So, what's the cleanest way, if any exists, to prepopulate the database with few groups and permissions?

Comment: Every data that I have to prepoulate my database I create a specific command. More or less a python program that runs separated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can associate those custom permissions with your models, try defining them under the [permissions attribute inside model's Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) class.

Create fixtures for your custom groups, but use [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) when serializing them, so that they refer to related permissions by their name rather than pk.